# Semigroup solving Schrödinger equation weakly is a unitary group

Tags: heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Thank you for reading!

**Setup:**

Let $(\mathcal{H},\langle \cdot |\cdot\rangle)$ be a separable complex Hilbert space, and $A:D(A)\to \mathcal{H}$ be a densely defined *symmetric* unbounded operator in $\mathcal{H}$ (i.e. $D(A)\subset \mathcal{H}$ is dense and $\forall \,u,\,v\in D(A):\,\langle u|Av\rangle = \langle Au|v\rangle$). The operator $(A,D(A))$ is *not* self-adjoint, but possesses self-adjoint extensions (its deficiency indices are equal).

Next, let $T:[0,\infty)\to B(\mathcal{H})$ be a strongly continuous semigroup such that for any $u\in D(A)$ the mapping $[0,\infty)\ni s\mapsto T(s)u\in \mathcal{H} $ is an element of $C([0,\infty),\mathcal{H})\cap C^1((0,\infty),\mathcal{H})$, and satisfies the differential equation
$$
\forall \,v\in D(A):\quad \left \langle \frac{d}{ds}T(s)u\,\middle|\, v \right\rangle+i\big\langle T(s)u\big |A v \big\rangle=0\,,\quad \forall s\in (0,\infty)\,.
$$

**Question:**

Is the map $T$ the restriction to $[0,\infty)$ of a unitary group $U$ generated by *some* self-adjoint extension of $(A,D(A))$?